# Insertar datos en un campo fecha de una base de datos access 2013 desde C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una base de datos de Access 2013 con varias tablas, y en algunas de ellas campos de tipo "Fecha Corta". El asunto es que al intentar introducir datos mediante una sentencia SQL INSERT desde C#, me da el siguiene error: "No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios."

Probé con otra tabla que no tiene campos fecha y no tuve ningún problema en hacer el INSERT, por lo que llegué a la conclusión de que el problema es el campo fecha.

El valor de la fecha lo estoy tomando de un DateTimePicker llamado dtpFechaNac.

Cómo debería formatear estos campos para que Access 2013 me los tome correctamente?

Formatos que probé:

```
- dtpFechaNac.Value
- dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
- dtpFechaNac.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

CODIGO (lo más relevante):

```
string cmd = string.Format("INSERT INTO DatosPersonales " +
                     "([Dni], [NombreApe], [Nacionalidad], [FechaNac], " +
                     "[Edad], [EstadoCiv], [Hijos], [Direccion], " +
                     "[Localidad], [CodigoPos], [Telefono], [Celular], " +
                     "[Educacion], [Email]) " +
                     "VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param6, " +
                     "@Param7, @Param8, @Param9, @Param10, @Param11, @Param12, " +
                     "@Param13, @Param14)");

        List<object> parametros = new List<object>();
        parametros.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtDni.Text));
        parametros.Add(txtNombreApe.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtNacionalidad.Text);
        parametros.Add(dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); //Aca esta el problema
        parametros.Add(txtEdad.Text);
        parametros.Add(cboEstadoCiv.SelectedItem.ToString());
        parametros.Add(txtHijos.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtDireccion.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtLocalidad.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtCodigoPos.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtTelefono.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtCelular.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtEducacion.Text);
        parametros.Add(txtEmail.Text);

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmd, CrearConexionDB());

if(parametros != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parametros.Count(); i++)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Param" + i.ToString(), parametros[i]);
            }
        }

        command.Connection.Open();
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

SOLUCIONADO:

No hay que convertir a string como bien dijo el amigo gbianchi, con tomar el valor directamente del DateTimePicker (en mi caso) la conversión se realiza automáticamente. El problema que tenía yo era que en la base de datos tenía otro campo definido como numérico que se me pasó por alto (error mío).

Comment: es muy pero muy probable que el problema sea el query... lo puedes mostrar?

Comment: Edito la pregunta así agrego el código

Comment: Editada: agregué el código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estas teniendo es que estas transformando la fecha a cadena antes de pasarla como parámetro, entonces la query queda mal construida al momento de pasársela a access.

Access trabaja las fechas entre `#`, por lo tanto si le pasaras un objeto fecha en lugar de string, access la transformaría según corresponda. Como no lo haces, Access la trata como un string y falla la conversión.

Es mas, yo te recomendaría eliminar la carga de los parámetros a una lista (que es de objetos, pero solo le pasas strings) y pasarlos directamente al objeto parameters del command.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Armo una lista de parametros porque tengo definida una función que la puedo llamar desde cualquier lado sin saber la cantidad de parametros que le voy a pasar, por eso esta hecho de esa forma.

Igualmente probe dejar solamente parametros.add(dtpFechaNac.value) pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: estas seguro que el problema es solo con las fechas? y los numeros?

Comment: No creo, ya que en otra tabla que tambien tiene campos numericos me lo toma bien.. se me ocurre que tal vez pueda ser que que al tomar el valor tal como viene del DateTimePicker me lo toma con formato fecha larga (con la hora, minutos y segundos) y en el access lo tengo definido como fecha corta?

Comment: puede ser.. proba mandar un objeto datetime fijo a ver que hace. si no, me encuentras en el chat.

Comment: Probé pero me da el mismo error.. leyendo en la web veo que hay o hubo muchísima gente con el mismo problema, pero sigo sin dar con la solución :(